# calling js file in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a js file with the following content, codes in the js file will be increasing in the future so there is no option of making it a .ts file i want it to be a js file only.

```
var myModule = {};
myModule.myFunction = function(){console.log('I am inside myJs.js file');};
exports.myModule = myModule;
```

now I have my angular project in which I am trying to import that as a module and use the object.

Maybe like?

```
import * as jsModule from 'myModule';
```

I have tried adding this in `angular.cli.json` under script tag and then create an entry in the `typings.d.ts` as `declare var myModule:any;`

but no luck.

Can someone help me understand how can I import that object in the angular 4 class file and use it?

Comment: No luck how? What happened? Was there an error? If so, what was the error? Did it fail silently? How did you try calling it?

Comment: it says it cannot file module 'myModule'

Comment: "_codes in the js file will be increasing in the future so there is no option of making it a .ts file_" can someone explain me this?

Comment: it means i cannot afford to change this js file into ts.

Comment: `import * as jsModule from 'myModule';`, is that the correct **path** to your module??

Comment: try this `import * as jsModule from 'relative path of js file'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### EDIT : TL;DR

1 - Your JS code is

```
var myModule = {};
myModule.myFunction = function(){console.log('I am inside myJs.js file');};
exports.myModule = myModule;
```

2 - Create a definition file containing

```
declare var myModule: { myFunction: Function };
```

3 - Import your definition file into your TS config (`tsconfig.json`)

```
"files": [
  "path/to/your/definition/file.d.ts"
]
```

4 - In your component, simply use (no declaration, nothing)

```
myModule.myFunction();
```

---

Every code written in Typescript (as long as it works, of course), will be Javascript compliant.

This means **yes**, you can create a `.ts` file with this (the syntax changes a bit, but still, it is the same code)

```
export const myModule = {
  myFunction: () => { console.log(`I'M PICKLE RIIIIIIIIIIIIIICK`); }
};
```

This is my two cents on this matter. But hey, you asked something, and I owe you an answer :

When you want to import a JS file into a TS file, what you need to do (assuming you're using angular CLI) is :

- Create your JS file (duh)
- open your `angular-cli.json` file
- find the `scripts` property
- add the JS file to this property (the default path starts at `src/`)

Now, your file is imported into your project. This leaves you two choices from that :

- Without auto-completion in your IDE :

  ```
  declare var myModule: any;
  myModule.myFunction();
  ```
- With auto-completion in your IDE : you will have to create a definition file, and add it to your typescript config.

  - In your `tsconfig.json`, at root :

    ```
    "files": [
      "path/to/your/definition/file.d.ts"
    ]
    ```

In your file `file.d.ts`

```
declare var myModule: { myFunction: Function };
```

And you will have to import every definition file, along with every property you want autocompleted in your IDE.

Now, the Typescript option doesn't seem that bad, does it ? :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am now getting this "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export"

Comment: Hum okay but from what, I offered you 3 different ways for your issue

Comment: with auto completion in my IDE, let me try the other one as well .

Comment: when I try with the Without auto-completion in your IDE method I get an error as [ts] Statements are not allowed in ambient contexts.
var myModule: any

Comment: Well I can't see your issue, I just tested it and my code is working fine. It's either you had an issue when writing `export const myModule` ( because I don't), or you stroked a key somewhere that bugs an export statement. As for your second issue, you need to add `declare` before var

Comment: let me rewrite this from the scratch and send you the response, thanks for your prompt response though!

Comment: No problem, but wait : have you created a TS file or a JS file ? Because if you created a JS file, you have to keep your first syntax ! The second syntax (the one I gave with the export) is for Typescript only

Comment: I have tried with the both :) first it did not work with js and switched to ts, but again no luck in either case.

Comment: Please see my edit, I shortened my answer to make it easier to read/understand

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some ways to import the JS file to Angular 4.
Here is one of common ways.

-script.store.ts

```
interface Scripts {
    name: string;
    src: string;
}
export const ScriptStore: Scripts[] = [
     {name: 'gmaps-scripts', src: '../../../assets/js/gmaps.js'},
];
```

-script.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {ScriptStore} from "./script.store";

declare var document: any;

@Injectable()
export class ScriptService {

private scripts: any = {};

constructor() {
      ScriptStore.forEach((script: any) => {
            this.scripts[script.name] = {
                loaded: false,
                src: script.src
            };
      });
 }

 load(...scripts: string[]) {
      var promises: any[] = [];
      scripts.forEach((script) => promises.push(this.loadScript(script)));
      return Promise.all(promises);
 }

 loadScript(name: string) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
           //resolve if already loaded
           if (this.scripts[name].loaded) {
               resolve({script: name, loaded: true, status: 'Already 
         Loaded'});
    }
    else {
        //load script
        let script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = this.scripts[name].src;
        if (script.readyState) {  //IE
            script.onreadystatechange = () => {
                if (script.readyState === "loaded" || script.readyState === "complete") {
                    script.onreadystatechange = null;
                    this.scripts[name].loaded = true;
                    resolve({script: name, loaded: true, status: 'Loaded'});
                }
            };
        } else {  //Others
            script.onload = () => {
                this.scripts[name].loaded = true;
                resolve({script: name, loaded: true, status: 'Loaded'});
            };
        }
        script.onerror = (error: any) => resolve({script: name, loaded: false, status: 'Loaded'});
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    }
});
  }

 }
```

-app.component.ts

```
....
import { ScriptService } from '../../../services/script/script.service';
declare var google: any;
declare var GMaps: any;

....

this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
      this._script.load('gmaps-scripts').then(data => {
           ......
      })
})
```